# How to add my own checkstyle in eclipse programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, checkstyle

I want to add my own customized checkstyle to eclipse workspace. I also want to set that checkstyle as a default one. Is there any API to do this? I have my own Checkstyle configuration file which i want to add and set as a global checkstyle for workspace in eclipse.

Comment: You need to give us more details. What do you mean by 'custom checkstyle'?

Answer (score 4):

First click on Help -> Eclipse marketplace and then search for checkstyle plugin and then install the plugin.
The Click on Window -> Preferences -> CheckStyle
Then click on New and import your own style and set as default.

For more details ([Checkstyle Plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/))

Also you can use project specific code formatter 
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code style -> Formatter 
Then you can import your own formatter